# Can I change Agent 8's appearance after starting Side Order?

Tags: splatoon-3, splatoon-3-side-order

Splatoon 3's DLC campaign Side Order starts with you customizing the appearance of Agent 8. I want to make them match my character from Splatoon 2, but I can't remember their appearance offhand.

Will I be able to change Agent 8's appearance after starting the Side Order campaign?

Comment: You can do it when on outside of tower